# ApostropheCMS workflow ignore incoming commits

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Is there any way to ignore commits from certain pieces or widgets ? Currently , I build a comment pieces and a comment will always appear in live mode of apostrophe workflow. But then , it keeps prompt the button for `submit` & `commit` . Is there any way to ignore ? Like `.gitignore` feature.

> Example use case : A public user submitted comment and the piece is maintain published. The piece is always available in live mode and user keep submitting the comments without any problem. But in draft mode , the button to submit & commit is always there. So is there any disable/ignore live changes for not making it to commit/submit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `excludeProperties` option of the `apostrophe-workflow` module to ignore your `comments` property.

```
'apostrophe-workflow': {
  excludeProperties: [ 'comments' ]
}
```

That property will then never be considered for purposes of whether a document needs to be committed, and also will never *be* committed.

(As I have previously mentioned, the use of an array property for comments is eventually going to bite you, the document will get too big for MongoDB or just impractical to send and receive. You really should joinByArray with a comment piece type instead or something similar, or just use Disqus if the site is open to the public anyway.)

Comment: Noted. And thanks for the tips ! I also researched the array limit in MongoDB and you were right about it. It says **The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.** . So scaling document using array is really bad thing. I'll configure my comments piece using alternative to joins or something similar :)